# Pin images change after map type change?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary

I am just loading a simple map with customize pin images on pin annotations. First time it loads the pin images in map correctly. When i change map type the pins are change in their default format.Guys do you have any idea about this problem. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `viewForAnnotation`, make sure you are creating a plain `MKAnnotationView` and not an `MKPinAnnotationView`.